# jQuery get children and give them numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, children

I need a jQuery function which should give children elements of a div differrent css attributes.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
</div>
```

The divs inside the container are automatically generated.

the children of the Element should have this css attributes:

```
First child: animation-delay: 1s;

Second child: animation-delay: 2s;

Third child: animation-delay: 3s;
```

...

I´ve tried it with nth:child via css but it didnt work so I need a jQuery solution.

Comment: *"so I need a jQuery solution"* .... show us what you tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is to help fix **your code** not do your work and research for you

Comment: Really this needs no Javascript or jQuery. It's just not `nth:child` but `:nth-child(n)`(see my answer below, added colors to make visible that it works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds the wanted css attribute:

```
$( ".container>div.autogenerated-div" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).css("animation-delay",(index+1)+"s");
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wxhrks0x/

Or do it with css less (without jQuery):

```
@iterations: 8;
.autogenerated-div-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
  .autogenerated-div-@{i} {
    animation-delay: ~"@{i}%"s;
  }
  .autogenerated-div-loop(@i - 1);
}
.autogenerated-div-loop (@iterations);
```

Comment: Remember that this will affect all `div` inside `.container`, not just direct child `div`. If it has to be jQuery (which in this case is completely unnecessary, it'd be safe to use `.container > .autogenerated-div` as a selector.

Comment: This lies in the responsibility of each programmer. The given code makes it possible to access elements as shown.

Comment: The given code has 8 child elements, so if that's what your argumentation would be based on, why do you criticize the CSS approach? Also, I'm not saying you *miss* the containers, I'm saying you also hit child divs inside the autogenerated divs.

Answer (score 3):

Really this needs no Javascript or jQuery. It's just not `nth:child` but `:nth-child(n)`:

```css
.container > :nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  color: red;
}
.container > :nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  color: blue;
}
.container > :nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  color: green;
}
.container > :nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div">OOO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML code is generated, so in my opinion it is not a good choice to write 4 nearly identical lines of code for each `animation-delay`. Imagine the SO will generate 30.000 div's. Then you have 120.000 lines of css code.

Comment: That is a valid point. In that case it'd be better to solve the problem with Javascript (I still wouldn't use jQuery here). In case of just some `div` it is clearly better, also performance-wise, to apply a purely CSS based solution. Also, consider the sitaution in which new divs will get dynamically added to the container. You'd have to re-run the jQuery every time.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with nth-child

```css
div.autogenerated-div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: newcolor 1s ease;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

div.autogenerated-div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: newcolor 1s ease;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

div.autogenerated-div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  animation: newcolor 1s ease;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes newcolor {
  to {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
  <div class="autogenerated-div"></div>
</div>
```